# JMX exporter для prometheus

Tags: java, yaml, prometheus, grafana, jmx

Такой вопрос, уже второй день мучаюсь с командой для запуска jmx-exporter:

```
java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.15.0.jar=8080:config.yaml -jar yourJar.jar
```

Мне нужно запустить JMX что бы собирать метрики томкатов через прометей. Я скачал файл .jar из документации что на гите. https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter#readme

Но никак не могу понять как мне его запустить, что бы он подтянул метрики из моего томката. Что за **config.yaml** где его брать ? и что за **-jar yourJar.jar**

Comment: Решил прикрепить ссылку где указано куда прописывать jmx  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812371/configuring-jmx-exporter-with-tomcat

Comment: Так же добавлю, для потомков:  Прописывать Javaagent нужно в конфиг томката находящийся в **/etc/default/tomcat(8,9 итд...)**  <br/>  **JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/prometheus/prometheus/jmx_exporter/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.15.0.jar=18081:/opt/prometheus/prometheus/jmx_exporter/jmx_exporter/example_configs/tomcat.yml"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта библиотека предназначена для использования с любой java программой путем внедрения java агента, она не запускается отдельно. Для того, чтоб добавить exporter метрик нужно передать дополнительные параметры, а именно опцию `-javaagent`, при старте JVM той программы, метрики из которой вы хотите экспортировать.

Java программа (в том числе и tomcat) запускается используя команду `java -jar имя_файла.jar`, которая стартует код из jar файла.

Для томката команда старта `java ...` упрятана в скриптах в каталоге bin. Обычно используют `startup.sh`/`startup.bat` или `catalina.sh`/`catalina.bat` (как вы запускаете томкат - это уж вам только известно). Дополнительные параметры для JVM можно передать через переменную окружения `CATALINA_OPTS`, что описано в `catalina.sh`:

> CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
> "run" or "debug" command is executed.
> Include here and not in JAVA_OPTS all options, that should
> only be used by Tomcat itself, not by the stop process,
> the version command etc.
> Examples are heap size, GC logging, JMX ports etc.

Так что перед запуском томкат добавляйте в переменную окружения дополнительную опцию `javaagent:...`.

Что касается `config.yaml`, то это описано подробнейшим образом с примером по ссылке что вы привели в разделе [Configuration](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter#configuration).

Comment: Но я также могу использовать tomcat.yml, из того же репозитория вместо этого конфига ?

Comment: Можете. Если конфигурация в нем указанная вам подходит.

Comment: Понял, огромное спасибо !